# coordination versions of related libs when i add new lib in project

Tags: java, maven, selenium, gradle, dependency-management

There is one lib for selenium
org.seleniumhq.selenium:**selenium-java** : **2.53.1**

org.seleniumhq.selenium: **selenium-server**: **2.44.0**

Now I need to add selenium server dependency for my new tasks in this project, but within adding selenium server dependency I meet problem that there are not some classes(as example '**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/ImmutableCapabilities**'), therefore I find in maven central modules that contains this classes and include them in project, but this modules has transitive dependencies that already exists in project(and have another versions)

key point is that transitive modules has not classes that I use in my first task related with selenium

How I may find true version for selenium server lib(and his transitive dependencies) that i could not try all combinations of libs versions

May be in gradle exist such function or exist separate tool or service for this

Comment: Show your maven dependency of selenium-java

Comment: init dependency 

compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.53.1'

Comment: additional dependencies, selenium server and other for his work

compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.5.2'
compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:2.5.0'
compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.44.0'

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency into Maven `pom.xml` as following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

you can change the version `3.11.0` to other, Maven will download all transitive dependencies for you.

You wanted class `ImmutableCapabilities` is neither in `selenium-java.jar` nor `selenium-sever.jar`. But in `selenium-api.jar` as following:

[image]